# How to escape input file for sed

Tags: linux, bash, unix, sed, zsh

I'm trying to make a simple bash script that takes an input file and replaces placeholders like `&date` by the actual value (the date in this case)

Example:

```
text=$(sed -e "s/&file/$FILE/" -e "s/&date/$DATE/" $FILE)
echo $text
```

Problems:

1. The newlines are removed, all the lines are jumbled together.
2. Things like `/******` placed in the start of the file are changed to `/bin /boot etc` (so the paths are resolved). `*****/` will also be replaced.

Example:

Input:

```
/**********************************
hello
**********************************/
```

Output (line broken in the middle to make it readable):

```
/bin /boot /dev /etc /home /lib /lib64 /mnt
/opt /proc /root /run /sbin /srv /sys /tmp /usr /var hello parent/ parent_neighbor/
```

I guess I need to escape the file, but I could not find anywhere how to do it.

Comment: Double-quote your shell variable references. Specifically, use `echo "$text"` instead of just `echo $text`. Also, get in the habit of running your scripts through [shellcheck.net](https://www.shellcheck.net), since it's good at pointing out common mistakes like this.

Comment: @GordonDavisson I tried putting quotes everywhere, except on the echo! I thought it was sed fault, but thinking about it, you’re right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The expansion of the root directory is happening because '/***********' is being interpreted by Bash *pathname expansion* as "root directory wildcard wildcard wildcard......"

I'd not even use sed for this, it's regex syntax is kind of unpleasant. How about Perl:

```
text=$(perl -pe 's/&file/'"$FILE"'/g; s/&date/'"$DATE"'/g' $FILE)
echo "$text"
```

as @Gordon Davisson said in the comment, the key here is to quote `"$text"` when it's used as an argument to `echo` so Bash doesn't treat "/***" as a path and expand it before `echo` is even invoked.

Edit: here's a link: http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/expansion/globs

Comment: I’m gonna select you cause Gordon didn’t put in an answer, although you don’t have to go with perl